# Mass/bulk forwarding emails based on tag, from one Gmail Business account to another

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

I need to forward (entire thread) a few hundred emails from one Gmail Business account to another based on the tag.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can Google Scripts to [Forward Gmail messages in bulk](http://www.labnol.org/internet/auto-forward-gmail-messages/20665/) based on labels.

Comment: Did forward 6 emails (the first six in a label with the same sender) then stuck. :angry: Also Uninstall just pops the "running script" yellow pop up - and does nothing - latest chrome

Comment: If uninstall isn't working, you can revoke access to the script under Google Accounts -> Security.

Comment: For the failures I got an email : apps-scripts-notifications@google.com : Summary of failures for Google Apps Script: Copy of Gmail Auto-Forward by Digital Inspiration : 
"Invalid mime type. (line 127, file "labnol")"